# Set "url" in Form with Fileupload

Tags: php, html, forms, web

I want to set the URL to `account.php?action=...` but it always set the URL to 
`account.php?file=...`
How can i avoid this?

```
<form action="account.php?action=uploadprofileimage" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="uploadprofileimagewrapper">
        <input id="uploadprofileimage" type="file" name="file" onchange="form.submit()">
    </div>
</form>
```

so how can I set the "URL"?

I want to disable the `file=...` or when its necessary have both in the URL so `file=...` **and** `action=...`

thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `method` attribute in `<form>` and set to `post`:

```
<form action="account.php?action=uploadprofileimage" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div id="uploadprofileimagewrapper">
        <input id="uploadprofileimage" type="file" name="file" onchange="form.submit()">
    </div>
</form>
```

See also: [HTML form enctype Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp)

Comment: thanks bro .... I'm so stupid ... how can i forget that ...